# Radio buttons in table - naming each row the same with php script (Likert Scale)

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table, radio-button

I have build a simple **likert scale** application which lets users to add as many likert question as they want (the code is below, you can try it).

So, the user create questions (likert) on the first page (*index.html*) after then, by submitting, they have a survey-like page (*execute.php*) that is presenting their likert scale questions.

**PROBLEM:** The thing is that everything works, except naming the input radio button in order to catch it by some php script later. It is named, but not every row has the same name so the likert scale doesn't work right. It should work like this: **Every row of radio buttons of each question should have one name.**

*FOR EXAMPLE*: For the first question: the radio buttons in the first row should have names *likert11, likert11, likert11*... The second row should be *likert12, likert12, likert12*...
And for the question 2: It should be *likert21, likert21*...

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<input type="submit" value="LIKERT" onclick="addlik();" />
<form action="execute.php" method="post">
<div id="brain1"></div><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK"><br/>
</form>
```

**SCRIPT.JS**

```
n=1;
function addlik() {
        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.name = "question[" + n + "]";
        textarea.rows = 2;
        textarea.cols = 60;
        var lik = document.createElement("textarea");
        lik.name = "lik[" + n + "]";
        lik.rows = 6;
        lik.cols = 30;
        var liko = document.createElement("textarea");
        liko.name = "liko[" + n + "]";
        liko.rows = 6;
        liko.cols = 30;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = n + ". Question: <br />" + textarea.outerHTML + "<br />The left textbox is for Items (vertical). The rigth one is for Options (header horizontal): <br/>" + lik.outerHTML + liko.outerHTML + "<br /><hr/><br/>";
        document.getElementById("brain1").appendChild(div);
        n++;
}
```

**EXECUTE.PHP**

```
<?php
$bla = "";
$question = $_POST['question'];
$length = count($_POST['question']);
$likoprint = array("","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","");
$tablerow = array("","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","");
$radiooptions = array("","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","");

for($j=1; $j<=$length; $j++) {
if($_POST['question'][$j] != "") {
        $lik = $_POST['lik'];
        $likarr[$j] = explode("\n", str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $lik[$j]));
        $liko = $_POST['liko'];
        $likoarr[$j] = explode("\n", str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $liko[$j]));
        $ln = 1;
        for($lo=0;$lo<sizeof($likoarr[$j]);$lo++) {
            $val = $lo + 1;
            $likoprint[$j] .= '<td>'.$likoarr[$j][$lo].'</td>';
            $radiooptions[$j] .= '<td><input type="radio" name="likert'.$j.$lo.'" value="'.$val.'"></td>';
        }
        for($l=0;$l<sizeof($likarr[$j]);$l++) {
        $tablehead = '<td>Items\Options</td>'.$likoprint[$j];
        $tablerow[$j] .= '<tr><td>'.$likarr[$j][$l].'</td>'.$radiooptions[$j].'</tr>';
        $table = '<table style="width:900px;"><tr>'.$tablehead.'</tr>'.$tablerow[$j].'</table>';
}
        $bla .= $j.') '.$question[$j].'<br/>'.$table.'<br/><br/>';
}}

echo $bla;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the radio value but this is not the best way possible. What you can do is use *one input name* for every answer(option) to the question, and in the *input value* use the value of the option. That way you get the option checked easily. Something like this:

```
for($lo=0;$lo<sizeof($likoarr[$j]);$lo++) {
    $val = $lo + 1;
    $likoprint[$j] .= '<td>'.$likoarr[$j][$lo].'</td>';
    $radiooptions[$j] .= '<td><input type="radio" name="likert'.$j.'" value="'.$val.'"></td>';
}
```

For accessing more than one option use checkbox, since it can easily be implemented, checked and unchecked:

```
for($lo=0;$lo<sizeof($likoarr[$j]);$lo++) {
    $val = $lo + 1;
    $likoprint[$j] .= '<td>'.$likoarr[$j][$lo].'</td>';
    $radiooptions[$j] .= '<td><input type="checkbox" name="likert['.$j.'][]" value="'.$val.'"></td>';
}
```

Comment: What about if I have three rows for each questions. Then only one option could be selected per question, and I want to select three. Each row of each question should have one answer (option).